# Migrating from PromiseKit wrap

Tags: ios, swift, promisekit

I'm trying to get rid of some warnings in my code and can't seem to migrate away from PromiseKit's `wrap`. Specifically, in 6.0 the release details say I shouldn't use it and should use `init(resolver:)` instead.

I had a function:

```
func foo(arg1: Int, arg2: Int, completionHandler: @escaping () -> ())
```

The following was working:

```
wrap({ foo(arg1: val1, arg2: val2, completionHandler: $0) })
```

I tried to change it to (what the release notes suggest):

```
Promise { foo(arg1: val1, arg2: val2, completionHandler: $0.resolve) }
```

This produced an error `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred` so I tried to fix that:

```
Promise<Void> { foo(arg1: val1, arg2: val2, completionHandler: $0.resolve) }
```

But that triggered a different error `Unable to infer closure type in the current context` and I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the `deprecated` method used to `wrap` the methods.

> ```
> @available(*, deprecated, message: "See `init(resolver:)`")
> public func wrap(_ body: (@escaping (Error?) -> Void) throws -> Void) -> Promise<Void> {
>     return Promise { seal in
>         try body(seal.resolve)
>     }
> }
> ```

As we can see, the `completion` closure is taking an `Optional` `Error` argument so i am suspicious how your older code was working by passing a wrong closure. I feel your `foo` method declaration should be like this,

```
func foo(arg1: Int, arg2: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    // body
}
```

However for the latest `PromiseKit`, you can update the `completionHandler` by passing an `Optional` `Error` as above to create `Promises` as below,

```
Promise { foo(arg1: 1, arg2: 2, completionHandler: $0.resolve) }
```

Comment: Thanks, that did point out the issue! My `completionHandler` was `@escaping () -> ()` and after changing to `(Error?) -> Void` it worked. Somehow this did build with `wrap` but not with `init`.